# how to deactivate apparmor profiles which i deleted

Tags: apparmor

ah I deleted the profiles for some of my programs. now i want to deactivate them but no avail. 
when first i try to disable the profile for example by

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump
```

I encountered error which says something like line 1 :unexpected symbol ...

so i removed the relevant profiles from apparmor.d but still profiles were enforced. then I try to put profiles in complain mode by aa-complain now obvious error is can not find profile.

any way to come out this situation

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on 64 bit machine

Answer (score 0):

after deleting profiles, I restarted my system. Now everything is fine, deleted profiles are deactivated.

cautionary note: plz never do copy/paste for profile writing as some hidden characters are added with this which can cause problem in future. i was unable to place profiles in complain mode due to such characters.